# Flash vanilla (AOSP) Android ROM on Xiaomi Redmi

Tags: rom-flashing, vanilla-android, xiaomi

I have a Xiaomi Redmi 1S.

Is it possible to flash a vanilla (AOSP) Android ROM? This MIUI is annoying me.  I have a few bugs which come from MIUI and I want to flash a vanilla ROM but always when I thought I've found the right one, it's bricked my phone and had to restore it with the custom MiFlash Tool.

Recovery on the phone was not even possible.

Comment: I changed to [tag:vanilla-android], since the definition of "stock ROM" is "MIUI" for Xiaomi. Anyway, it seems there are many "custom" AOSP ROM for Xiaomi. Searching for "Redmi AOSP ROM" might help you.